# Ecto.DateTime how to deal with timezones?

Tags: datetime, elixir, ecto

I set a timestamp on certain records in a Ecto changeset (for example when a record has entered a different state, when a message has been sent, etc.)

Now there are two ways how I could do that. Using local time or UTC. For example:

```
def changeset_utc(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:from, :to, :sent_at, :subject, :content])
  |> set_sent_at_utc
end

def changeset_local(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:from, :to, :sent_at, :subject, :content])
  |> set_sent_at_local
end

defp set_sent_at_local(changeset) do
  datetime = :calendar.universal_time() |> :calendar.universal_time_to_local_time() |> Ecto.DateTime.from_erl
  put_change(changeset, :sent_at, datetime)
end

defp set_sent_at_utc(changeset) do
  datetime = :calendar.universal_time() |> Ecto.DateTime.from_erl
  put_change(changeset, :sent_at, datetime)
end
```

So from my understanding it is preferable to store time in UTC. If I would store time as local time things would get very messy as soon as I have to deal with different time zones.

But what I was wondering: Is there a better way to handle this? Is there a way to store DateTime with a timezone?

Comment: You can try `Timex`.It has `Timex.Ecto.DateTimeWithTimeZone` https://hexdocs.pm/timex/using-with-ecto.html

Comment: For storing date/time with timezone information I use is [Calendar.DateTime](https://hexdocs.pm/calendar/Calendar.DateTime.html).

Comment: As a general approach it is most common to store dates in UTC. Then for logged in users you can prompt them for their preferred timezone and convert the utc dates from the database to their timezone when displaying them. There are some kinds of objects where it makes sense to store a timezone for example if your storing a Conference you may need to store the timezone the conference is held in but you'd typically put the timezone in a separate column.

Comment: @Bruce do you know how I would go about converting them?

Comment: If using the Timex library, use `Timex.convert/2` (for others who may find this question).

Comment: For others coming here, there is no `Timex.convert/2` anymore. I don't know when it was removed, but now you can use `Timex.to_datetime/2` (https://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.html#to_datetime/2).